# Get selected value with PHP and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, users, select

I have form that i'm using to update user profile from front end and i have country select.

```
<form method="post" id="adduser" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <select id="te" name="usercountry_id">
        <option value="1">Country 1</option>
        <option value="2">Country 2</option>
    </select>

    <p class="form-submit">
    <?php echo $referer; ?>
    <input name="updateuser" type="submit" id="updateuser" class="submit button" value="<?php _e('Update', 'profile'); ?>" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user' ) ?>
    <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update-user" />
    </p><!-- .form-submit -->
</form><!-- #adduser -->
```

When i try to update

```
$usercountry= $_POST['usercountry_id'];
update_user_meta($id, 'usercountry_id', $usercountry);
```

my `$_POST['usercountry_id']` is empty. Also i tried using jQuery to pass variable to php but with no success:

```
 jQuery("#te").click(function() {
    var b = jQuery('#te :selected').text();

    var ajaxurl ='<?php echo get_bloginfo("url"); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
       jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {"variable": b },

    });});
```

`$_POST['variable']` is again empty.

Comment: Post the code that does the form processing, please.

Comment: You might want to take this question to SO - there it'd be on-topic, anyway. Though, as an aside, `$_POST['usercountry_id']` should be populated with either `1` or `2` after form submit.

Comment: Ok, i found what was the problem. I called $_POST in form itself instead of in form processing code. I was using default wordpress form processing code for user profile. 

     if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user') {
            if(!empty($_POST['usercountry_id']))
            update_user_meta($current_user -> id, 'usercountry_id',  esc_attr($_POST['usercountry_id']));}

Thank you

Comment: Please add the last comment as answer and mark it as solution for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found what was the problem. I called $_POST in form itself instead of in form processing code. I was using default WordPress form processing code for user profile.

```
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user' ) { 
    if ( !empty( $_POST['usercountry_id'] ) )
        update_user_meta($current_user -> id, 'usercountry_id', esc_attr( $_POST['usercountry_id'] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this, try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('te').value = "<?php echo $_GET['usercountry_id'];?>";
</script>
```